# Trying to use Sed with regex to fetch data from a log file

Tags: command-line, regex, sed

Hello I am experience difficulty to extract data from log file with sed -E command.I see regex is different than this I use in python.

```
INFO [2020-05-10 17:37:34] [armada.gloge]  Username [109/15654]
```

Data I need it is number 109.I can`t produce regex expression to do so.Thank you.

```
echo "Username [132" | sed -E '[^Username\s+]'
```

output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `['
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed -E` does not expect a regex, it expects a sed script with sed commands. Some sed commands use regular expressions. Your script begins with `[` which is not a sed command, hence `unknown command`.

Your task can be completed by a single `s` command:

```
sed -E 's|.*\[([^/]*).*|\1|'
```

The search pattern is:

- `.*\[` – take everything up to the last literal `[` (the last one because `*` is greedy); instead of `.*\[` you can use `.*Username \[` to find the `[` just after `Username`, even if it's not the last one;
- `([^/]*)` – then take as many non-`/` as you can, as a group;
- `.*` – then take the rest.

Because of `.*` in front and `.*` at the end, the whole patter will match the entire line, *if the middle part matches anything*. The replacement is `\1`, which means the first (in our case the only) capturing group defined by `()`.

Non matching lines will be printed as they are. If this is not what you want, tell `sed` to only print after `s` succeeds:

```
sed -E 's|.*\[([^/]*).*|\1|;t;d'
```

where

- `t` makes `sed` branch to the end of the script if `s` succeeded; at the end of the script `sed` prints by default;
- `d` is only reached after `t` didn't work (which means `s` didn't perform the substitution), it makes `sed` forget the current line, read the next one and start the script over.

Another approach is e.g. to delete lines not containing `Username [` and only process what's left:

```
sed -E '/Username \[/ ! d
        s|.*\[([^/]*).*|\1|'
```

Here `/Username \[/` matches against `Username [`, `!` negates, so `d` runs only for lines not containing `Username [`. In this case you can interpret `d` as "delete the line".

---

Just in case: you make `sed` process a file with

```
sed … thefile
# or
<thefile sed …
```